# Protocol extension init results in compile time seg fault: 11

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm not quite sure how to diagnose this as the error is quite verbose and abstract in the build log.
I've pasted the log here: https://pastebin.com/NmzFam5t

If I put the following into any project I'll get a seg fault 11 when I try to compile (not to mention SourceKit falls off a cliff)

```
protocol FeedProviderDelegate {

    associatedtype Item

    func feedWillChange()
    func feed(item: Item, changed: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, atIndex: Int?, newIndex: Int?)
    func feedDidChange()
}

protocol FeedProvider {

    associatedtype Item
    associatedtype Delegate: FeedProviderDelegate

    var delegate: Delegate? { get }
    var items: [Item] { get }
}

protocol SortDescriptorKeyProvider {
    static var sortableKeyPath: String { get }
    static var keyPathSortsAscending: Bool { get }
}

protocol EntityFeed: FeedProvider where
    Self: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
    Item: NSManagedObject & SortDescriptorKeyProvider {

    var delegate: Delegate? { get }
    var items: [Item] { get }
    var predicate: NSPredicate? { get }
    var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Item>? { get }

    init(
        controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Item>,
        delegate: Delegate?,
        predicate: NSPredicate?)
}

extension EntityFeed {

    init(delegate: Delegate, predicate: NSPredicate?) {

        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

        let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> =
            NSFetchRequest(entityName: Item.entity().managedObjectClassName)
        request.predicate = predicate
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(
            key: Item.sortableKeyPath,
            ascending: Item.keyPathSortsAscending)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        let controller: NSFetchedResultsController<Item> =
            NSFetchedResultsController(
                fetchRequest: request,
                managedObjectContext: context,
                sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                cacheName: nil) as! NSFetchedResultsController<Self.Item>

        self.init(
            controller: controller,
            delegate: delegate,
            predicate: predicate)
    }

}
```

when I comment out the init all is well, is there something obviously wrong there?

Comment: I would be nice to see the crash log, a lot can be seen from that :)

Comment: @Sulthan you're right :-) - I've updated the post with a link to the log.

Comment: Please, report a bug anyway. I am not sure if default `init` in extension can even work with another required `init`.